# How come π and π/10 appear to have the same relative error when represented as binary64?

Tags: floating-point

Suppose that you quickly want to determine which of π or π/10 has the largest relative error when represented in the IEEE 754 binary64 format. Also, you only have a C compiler at hand.

You might write the C program below, or a more compact version of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

volatile long double pil = 3.14159265358979323846L;
volatile double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;

volatile long double tpil = 0.314159265358979323846L;
volatile double tpi = 0.314159265358979323846;

int main() {

  volatile long double abs = pil - pi;

  printf("%La\n%La\n%La\n", pil, (long double)pi, abs);

  printf("pi:   abs err %La -> rel %La\n", abs, abs / pil);

  volatile long double abst = tpil - tpi;
  printf("pi/10: abs err %La -> rel %La\n", abst, abst / tpil);

}
```

The funny thing is that this program shows the relative errors of π and π/10 to be identical:

```
0xc.90fdaa22168c235p-2
0xc.90fdaa22168cp-2
0x8.d4p-56
pi:   abs err 0x8.d4p-56 -> rel 0xb.3d85789395e215bp-58
pi/10: abs err 0xe.2p-60 -> rel 0xb.3d85789395e215bp-58
```

I have added the `volatile` qualifiers and the intermediate computations to look at the generated assembly and make sure that this wasn't a compiler bug. It apparently isn't.

This is strange because many other values v do not have the property that the relative error of v is the same as the relative error of v/10. I checked with 0.1 and 0.3. Also this is not a question of magnitude, because 3 and 3.5 obviously have different relative errors than their respective tenths. Although 5, 10, 15, … do have the same relative error as their respective tenths, but these should be considered the exceptions.

Now, the program does not compute the exact values of the relative errors. It only has 12 bits to represent them (one sign bit plus 11 bits of difference between a 64-bit significand and a 53-bit significand). So there may have been a priori something like one chance in 4096 for the absolute error of π to turn out as 10 times the absolute error of π/10.

This still seems like an unlikely coincidence. Was the a priori chance that a real constant taken between 3 and 3.5 had the same relative error than its tenth when represented as `double` larger than my intuition says it should be? Or is there another way to see it, such as “this happens as soon as (double)(π/10)'s significand has enough trailing zeroes for its multiplication by ten to be exact”, which seems much more frequent (close to 1/8)?

Comment: Using an MP package, I confirm the observation but error values differ:`pi      =  4000 C90FDAA2 2168C000 00000000 00000...
pi      =  4000 C90FDAA2 2168C234 C4C6628B 80DC1...
abs err = -1.2246467991473532e-016  -0x1.1a6263p-53
rel err = -3.8981718325193755e-017  -0x1.678afbp-55
pi/10   =  3FFD A0D97BB4 E7870000 00000000 00000...
pi/10   =  3FFD A0D97BB4 E78701C3 D09EB53C 67167...
abs err = -1.2246467991473531e-017  -0x1.c3d09fp-57
rel err = -3.8981718325193755e-017  -0x1.678afbp-55`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way to look at this question is to notice that the significand of the `double` nearest π is a multiple of 5:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

volatile long double pil = 3.14159265358979323846L;
volatile double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;

volatile long double tpil = 0.314159265358979323846L;
volatile double tpi = 0.314159265358979323846;

void print_significand(double d) {
  uint64_t significand;

  memcpy(&significand, &d, 8);
  significand &= ((uint64_t)1<<52) - 1;
  significand |= (uint64_t)1<<52;

  printf("%" PRIx64 " %" PRIu64 "\n",
     significand, significand);
}

int main() {

  printf("Significand of (double)pi: ");
  print_significand(pi);

  printf("Significand of (double)(pi/10): ");
  print_significand(tpi);
  …
```

This shows:

```
Significand of (double)pi: 1921fb54442d18 7074237752028440
Significand of (double)(pi/10): 141b2f769cf0e0 5659390201622752
```

The integer 5659390201622752 is exactly 7074237752028440 / 5 * 4. The multiplication by four serves to keep the `double` representing π/10 normalized.

So given an arbitrary real r chosen uniformly between 2 and 4, approximated by the nearest double `d`, there is one chance in five that the significand of `d` is a multiple of 5. When this happens, `d/10.0` is exact. This makes `d/10.0` a very good candidate for the title of “double nearest to r/10”.

**How good a candidate?**

If the division by 10 takes us from the top of the binade (just below 4) to the bottom of the binade (just above 0.25), then the representable doubles are comparatively less dense around r/10 than they are around r, and there is no chance of finding a closer double to r/10 than `d/10.0`.

If the division by 10 takes us from the bottom of the binade (just above 2) to the top of the binade (just below 0.25), then doubles are comparatively denser around r/10 than they are around r. There is a chance that a better double approximation for r/10 than `d/10.0` exists, especially if `d` is already a bad approximation for r.

The cut-off point is `2.5`. The real π is above this cut-off point, so knowing that the significand of its `double` approximation was divisible by 5 was enough to infer that π/10 would be approximated by the tenth of the approximation of π, and that the relative errors of both approximations would be the same.